# How to take class type from string for MethodInfo MakeGenericMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm pretty unexperienced with using Reflection in C# so I try to follow the official example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to get a grasp on how things are working. To make this more closer to my real world scenarion I have changed the code a bit:

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Generic<T>(T toDisplay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere it is: {0}", toDisplay);
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        RefTests rt = new RefTests();
        rt.ExecuteMethodWithReflection();
    }
}

public class RefTests
{ 
    public void ExecuteMethodWithReflection()
    {
        //Type myType = typeof(Example);
        Type argType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        Type myType = Type.GetType("Example");
        MethodInfo method = myType.GetMethod("Generic");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(argType);
        object[] args = { 42 };
        generic.Invoke(null, args);
    }
}
```

The problem for me here is in  `ExecuteMethodWithReflection()` method. In the original example it's shown that the type of the class where the method is defined is taken like this:

```
Type myType = typeof(Example);
```

However in my real scenarion `Example` will be a string which I need to cast to the class type `Example` az you can see:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("Example");
```

But the problem here is that `myType` is `null` and at the edn I get exception because of that. I tried to keep things as simple as possible. As you can see from my example all the classes are in one file, sharing the same namespace. How am I supposed to modify my code so I can use string to get this type?

Comment: `Type.GetType` will work only if class resides inside `mscrolib` or calling assembly, or a assembly qualified name is required, otherwise it will return null. Is that the case? use `Assembly.GetType` instead.

Comment: You want to use the Assembly/Domain qualified name. Its in the form of `MyApp.Namespace.Example, MyApp`.

Comment: @Sriram Sakathivel Yeah, you and `pwas` are both right. Ultimately I want to be more flexible and get the fully qualified name during runtime. Could you help me with example on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifyt full name of the type including namespace:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.Example");
```

Sample for `int` works, because you specified also namespace `"System.Int32"`. When you provide only `"Int32"` it will return `null`.

Like **Sriram Sakthivel** has noticed, the `Type.GetType` without assembly-qualified name is working only

> in currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dl

otherwise - you need to supply yhe assembly-qualified name for the type.

**Edit**
In order to get type you could do the like this:

```
Assembly assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
//Assembly assm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
//Assembly assm   = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
//Assembly assm = Assembly.Load("//");
// it depends in which assmebly you are expecting the type to be declared

// Single protects us - if more than one "Example" type will be found (with different namespaces)
// throws exception (we don't know which type to use)
// when null - type not found
Type myType = assm.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(type => type.Name.Equals("Example"));
```

Comment: That's not enough, See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903303/how-to-take-class-type-from-string-for-methodinfo-makegenericmethod#comment38688291_24903303) here

Comment: Yeah, I knwo but `Example` the type is inside in executing assembly - so - it it is engouh.

Comment: @ Sriram Sakthivel What's more, it is not "mscrolib or calling assembly" - according to MSDN it's "currently **executing** assembly or in Mscorlib.dll" - it's a difference.

Comment: @pwas Thanks, it's working. Just, if you know how, can you provide me with example how to make it more generic (to find in runtime the full name which I need to provide)?